# How can i include standard html in React .jsx file?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I am working on a project web project written by someone else so am learning as I am programming.

I have a login screen and on the screen is a text box for email and password. Now the way they have been constructed is that in the jsx file there is the following:

```
         <FormString  Id= "" Label="" Icon=""....... />
         <FormPassword  Id="" Label=" "......./>
```

do i need to define a  or can i simply use html select options like the following ?

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, just make sure to use className instead of class, as it is a reserved keyword in JS and needs to be substituted. It is not listed in your example but could be a pitfall when inserting regular HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put your code as return from your component(you can create yours - FormCar, or return it from example you have), and remember you have to have only one parent and all you tags should be in, as in my example one parent is div tag.

```
  return (
    <div>
    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    )
```

Also you can use your html with components you already have

```
  return (
    <div>
      <FormString  Id= "" Label="" Icon=""....... />
      <FormPassword  Id="" Label=" "......./>
      <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
        <select name="cars" id="cars">
         <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
         <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    )
```

Comment: this is so confusing , but yes it solved the problem. I am more familiar with AngularJS. In angular we usually can define a Model on the top of the .cshtml page,  like @model MyCarsApp.Models.CarsModel.   I can then do a check like                                                                                                                "@if (Model.Cars.Count > 0)" and then show the select .. Not sure if can be done here ?

Comment: hmm not sure what do you mean, in react we manage all by state, and i cant see your code if there a class component or hooks, i would recommend you to look at react doc, or some fast course, it will help you a lot more than guessing what to do, react and angular different. And if  my answer helped you, please mark it as correct one) thank you so much

Comment: Go through [link 1](https://reactjs.org/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html) and [link 2](https://dottedsquirrel.com/react/rethinking-soc-with-react). It will help you to understand why **React** has built and **why it has built in this way** ( `React` challenges the traditional models of thinking towards the separation of concern).

Comment: Yes I think i will go through the react doc and stop the guessing.